# Unable to add to a csharp dictionary definition, recieveing "Object Reference Not Set to an instance..."

Tags: c#

Hey Guys, I'm trying to add to a dictionary, and recieveing the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error. Which I think means that what I'm trying to set it to doesn't exist?

This is the relevant code:

```
                Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>> user = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>>();
            user.Add("approved", null);
            user.Add("pending", null);
            user.Add("declined", null);
            int zz = 0;

            while (results.Read())
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> field = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                for (int i = 0; i < results.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    switch (fds[i].ToString())
                    {
                        case "gender":
                            string gend = ((Convert.ToBoolean(results[i])) == false) ? "Male" : "Female";
                            field.Add("gender", gend);
                            break;
                        default:
                            field.Add(fds[i], results[i].ToString());
                            break;
                    }
                }
                string status = results[0].ToString();
                user["approved"].Add(zz, field);
                zz++;
            }
```

Is there an issue with the way I am setting the three dictionaries at the beginning?
Thanks,

Psy

Comment: At what line is the add failing? You have multiple adds

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a third level in your nested dictionary structure, and you're skipping initialization of the second level. At the very least, you need to add:

```
user["approved"] = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>();
```

What would probably be better, is to do initialization further up front:

```
user.Add("approved", new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>());
user.Add("pending", new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>());
user.Add("declined", new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>());
```

Personally, I wouldn't use a Dictionary for `user` at all. It implies that there are a variable number of statuses of a request (or whatever), while in fact there is a finite amount of possibilities: pending, approved, declined. In my opinion, you would be better off writing a class that holds 3 collections for that.

This also helps in that you wouldn't have three nested Dictionaries, making the code more readable. It was enough to confuse you, let alone someone maintaining the code after you :)

Comment: I knew there was a step I was forgetting! Thanks!

The reason I'm using dictionaries is that I need to loop through the results again, this is just a way I use to make sure they are properly sorted by their status.

Answer (score 2):

You never create a `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>` object, so in the line of code:

```
user["approved"].Add(zz, field); // user["approved"] is null
```

Answer (score 1):

`user` is a dictionary mapping `string`s to a dictionary (the details of which aren't important for our purposes). The line

```
user.Add("approved", null);
```

adds an entry to `user` mapping `"approved"` to the `null` dictionary. You never set the dictionary that `"approved"` is mapped to a non-`null` dictionary so that when you hit the line

```
user["approved"].Add(zz, field);
```

you are trying to invoke the method `Dictionary.Add` on a `null` dictionary. You can fix this by adding the line

```
user["approved"] = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>();
```

The same applies to the other two entries in `user`.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
user["approved"] = field;
```

The line:

```
user["approved"].Add(zz, field);
```

bangs with a `NullReferenceException` because when you access `user["approved"]` it returns null because it's not initialized.